# Javascript get string value in a tag

Tags: javascript, string

I have a question about how to read the string betweena tag, for example.

```
Devices connecting to HOME <a onclick="kmt_Toggle('BOX01', this)" class="cs_answer_link" value="[Show me how to download and install my map..]">[Show me how to download and install my map..]</a><br />
<br />
<div class="cs_answer_secondAccordion" id="BOX01" style="display: none;">
Steps for downloading and installing a map...
</div>
```

My code a simple, when users click on the a tag, the div class will show, and change Show me how to download and install map string in a tag to Close. When users click again, the current "close" will become "original long text". My main issue is that How i can read the string between a tag, thanks. I can not use JQuery

```
  function kmt_Toggle(obj, aTag) {
  var el = document.getElementById(obj);
  if ( el.style.display != 'none' ) {
      el.style.display = 'none';
      //var tagString=document.ge(aTag).valueOf();

     // aTag.innerHTML='[more..]';
    aTag.innerHTML= tagString;
  }
  else {
      el.style.display = '';
      aTag.innerHTML='[close..]';
  }
     }
```

---

Hello Guys, thanks.

I think i have not made my question crystal clear. I want to build a toggle function in this Javascript, if people clicks on a tag, for instance,

```
<a onclick="kmt_Toggle('BOX01', this)" class="cs_answer_link" value="[Show me how to download and install my map..]">[Show me how to download and install my map..]</a>
```

It will show my div if my div has style = none;  and change Show me how to download and install map into "close"

Steps for downloading and installing a map...

If people click on the link again, it will go back to the "show me how to download and installl map" and hide my div.

I tried to build something by following idealmachine solution. It does not work.

Cheers,
Qing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `value` attribute of an `a` element is not officially standardized by the W3C. You don't need it.

That said, some lines of code that might work are:

```
// innerHTML way
aTag.originalInnerHTML = atag.innerHTML; // to save the innerHTML
aTag.innerHTML = '[close..]';            // to add new link text
aTag.innerHTML = aTag.originalInnerHTML; // to restore the innerHTML


// W3C DOM way
// Save
var cur = aTag.firstChild;
aTag.oldChildNodes = [];
while(cur) {
    aTag.oldChildNodes.push(cur);
    cur = cur.nextSibling;
}

// Add new link text
while(aTag.lastChild) aTag.removeChild(atag.lastChild);
aTag.appendChild(document.createTextNode('[close..]'));

// Restore
while(aTag.lastChild) aTag.removeChild(atag.lastChild);
for(var i = 0; i < aTag.oldChildNodes.length; ++i) {
    aTag.appendChild(aTag.oldChildNodes[i]);
}
```

Or you could do either of these instead, similar to how you are switching the accordion sections on and off:

- Insert both link texts into the HTML, then use CSS `display: none;` to switch off the one you do not want.
- Switch between entire `a` elements using CSS `display: none;`.

Comment: Hi idealmachine,  thankks. I tried w3c DOM way. I got a error,

Comment: cur = cur.nextSibling;
alert(cur) // Null value

Comment: I found out a way. I change my javascript like that  <div class="code">"function kmt_Toggle(obj, aTag) {
  var el = document.getElementById(obj);
  //Save original Store at the firs time.
  if(!aTag.originalInnerHTML)
   {
      aTag.originalInnerHTML=aTag.innerHTML;
   }
   
  if (el.style.display != 'none' ) {
      el.style.display = 'none';
      aTag.innerHTML=  aTag.originalInnerHTML;
  }
  else if( el.style.display =='none'){
      el.style.display = '';
      aTag.innerHTML='[close..]';
  }

     }" </div> //First I store aTag text string into a variables

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
getElementsByTagName("tagName")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

or:

```
getElementsById("id")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the

```
documentElement. getElementsByTagName( "div" )
```

you have do define after if you want the first element or second etc

like so

```
documentElement. getElementsByTagName( "div" ).item(0).innerHtml;
```

will give you the innehtml of the first occurance of div

or if you have an id

```
documentElement. getElementsById('idname')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
return document.getElementById(<your div name>).innerHtml;
```

Comment: Hi idealmachine,  thankks. I tried w3c DOM way. I got a error,  cur is null value. 
 while(cur) {
      aTag.oldChildNodes.push(cur);
      cur = cur.nextSibling;
      alert(cur);
  }

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way. I change my javascript like that

```
function kmt_Toggle(obj, aTag) {
        var el = document.getElementById(obj);
        //Save original Store at the firs time.
        if(!aTag.originalInnerHTML)
         {
            aTag.originalInnerHTML=aTag.innerHTML;
         }

        if (el.style.display != 'none' ) {
            el.style.display = 'none';
            aTag.innerHTML=  aTag.originalInnerHTML;
        }
        else if( el.style.display =='none'){
            el.style.display = '';
            aTag.innerHTML='[close..]';
        }

        }"
```

//First I store aTag text string into a variables